# jQuery Animate callback not invoked after animation performed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, infinite-carousel

I'm using jQuery `.animate()` to create an infinite carousel.  I've used `.animate()` before without any issues.  This time however, the animation is not completing.

It's a very simple animation, changing `margin-left` to a different value.  The value changes, and to me it looks as though it is complete, but the function does not fire.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#scrollLeft").click(function(){
      $("#scrollContent").animate(
        {'margin-left':'-714px'},
        {queue:false, duration:500},
        function(){
            alert("finishedLeft");
      });
  });
  $("#scrollRight").click(function(){
      $("#scrollContent").animate(
        {'margin-left':'-1190px'},
        {queue:false, duration:500},
        function(){
            alert("finishedRight");
      });
  });
</script>
```

The problem area is the carousel at the bottom of the page.  I am running off of `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`.

I guess my main question is, what could be preventing this function from firing, even though it seems as though the event is complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Watch your syntax.](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/HBCn5/

```
$("#scrollLeft").click(function() {
    $("#scrollContent").animate({
        'margin-left': '-714px', // don't close out the parameters with parentheses yet ...
        queue: false,            // continue adding the queue option (if needed)
        duration: 500            // and the duration option (if needed) and close after
    }, function() {
        alert("finishedLeft");
    });
});
$("#scrollRight").click(function() {
    $("#scrollContent").animate({
        'margin-left': '-1190px', // same as above
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    }, function() {
        alert("finishedRight");
    });
});​    ​
```

Comment: Well, I feel silly. I could've sworn that the changes were separate from the properties of the animation.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Haha, no worries. If you could make it the chosen answer that would be great :)

Comment: yeah, there's a waiting period before you can accept an answer.  I've got my eye on the countdown :)

Comment: I had the same problems, I was following the jQuery parameter format in their examples and the syntax suggested to do it the way that the asker had shown in his example. Solution: all of the parameters and options can be strung up into one parenthesis group, separated by commas.